# how to automatically remove browser cache?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

hi i am using ajax auto complete function in one of my forms. But my problem is over a period of time these suggestions gets stored and , instead of ajax auto complete list browser's suggestion list comes which hides my ajax list. how can remove this browser cache? and will this remove my session variable also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Unfortunately generally speaking its more controlled by the physical browser than it is the code you are writing. And I believe generally speaking you don't have access to the cache other than sessions and cookies from your own domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be enough to just set your Form's autocomplete to *off*:

See more here: [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag), https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Comment: worth mentioning is autocomplete in the sense of on or off doesn't work in older browsers, but its not highly likely anyone is using older browsers anymore or as much. But for compatibility concerns if those worry you.